# how to get data from grep result?

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I want to grep data in between `<td>` and `</td>`

examples:

- required `1` from `<td>1</td>`
- required `6` from `<td>6</td>`

so how to get that data?

Comment: We need to see your input and desired output...

Comment: What do you want with that Data? Copy in a variable?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. Where is the data? In a file? In a shell variable? Are the `<td>` and `</td>` on the same line? Can they have anything other than a number between them? Will there only be one pair per line? One per file? Many? We can't help you parse data you do not show us.

Comment: also, will the entire file consist of just one line with no linefeeds? (not uncommon with html fetched from a web server).    and will the html you're fetching tomorrow be formatted the same as what you're fetching today while you're writing the script.

Comment: @Ravexina i grep from one website till this and not able to grep that value so i need help

Answer (score 2):

Through `grep` if multiple times in a line:

```
grep -oP '(?<=<td>).*?(?=</td>)' infile.txt
1
6
```

Through `awk` and same if multiple times in a line:

```
awk -v FS="(<td>|</td>)" '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) print $I}' infile.txt
```